# Not able to get the TopBar on the viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabbar

i have a tabbar controller which i created from code. the first tab is the contacts tab.i need a bar on the top of this view controller so that i can add buttons like (+),(edit),(import) to do the appropriate action. for the contactsviewcontroller i have the viewdidload method as so.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {



self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add_clicked:)];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

}

But still i am not able to get the bar on the top with the 2 buttons. what am i doing wrong.

Comment: For starters, you should always call `[super viewDidLoad]` at the very beginning of the method.

Comment: i tried that as well and it did not work.